# SQL Aliases how to understand it?

Tags: sql

I don't understand this form either.

```sql
SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, c.CustomerName
FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o
WHERE c.CustomerName='Around the Horn' AND c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID;
```

AND

```sql
SELECT CustomerID AS ID, CustomerName AS Customer
FROM Customers;
```

From the second example, I understand that I select id and change it to display time as ID, but why do we need CustomerName AS Customer? I do not understand,
is also not clear, if we choose CustomerID, then where do the names come from? we didn't choose them

why point out oh, s. it only creates confusion and misunderstanding what is it for?

SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName AS ID, Name
FROM Customers;
this is how the code is clear but does not work))

Comment: You don't _need_ aliases (most of the time), but they are convenient.

Comment: I just want to understand how they work, for example, I don't understand at all how they display information if the desired column is not selected in the query.

Comment: In `SELECT CustomerID AS ID, CustomerName AS Customer` you select two columns:  CustomerID which you call ID in your result set, and CustomerName which you call Customer in your result set. You would like a syntax like `SELECT (CustomerID, CustomerName) AS (ID, Name) FROM Customers`, but this is not supported. There is no `AS` working on multiple columns, you need one `AS` per column.

Comment: Here I don’t understand where then you need to enter this AS,If I select CustomerID then why does it output the name?

Comment: You select two columns: `CustomerID AS ID` and `CustomerName AS Customer`. So in your result you see two columns, one containing the CustomerID titled with ID, and one containing CustomerName titled with Customer.

Comment: On a side note: You are learning SQL. But the join syntax you are using here: `FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o WHERE c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID` is completely out-dated. We changed the way we join tables in the year 1992. Since then we write the join as `FROM Customers AS c INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID`. If they still teach you to join this old way, you may want to quit your class, tutorial or book and look for a better one.

Comment: got it all thanks,I understand thank you but
Customers AS c INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
this is a record form and much that is connected with JOIN, it's hard for me to understand

Comment: SELECT A.CustomerName AS CustomerName1, B.CustomerName AS CustomerName2, A.City
FROM Customers A, Customers B
WHERE A.CustomerID <> B.CustomerID
AND A.City = B.City 
ORDER BY A.City;I understand the first line, it creates columns, but it’s not clear why write after from Customers A, Customers B, why do we need these A B? And EVERYTHING below is also not clear what is happening

Comment: You are looking at queries that you don't understand yet. So, learn all the basics till you get there. In the query the customers table is joined to itself. The condition is that each customer is joined to all other customers in the same city.

Comment: I understand, but how they get to examples I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one:

```sql
SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, c.CustomerName
FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o
WHERE c.CustomerName='Around the Horn' AND c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID;
```

This is basically aliasing table name so that you don't have to write the full names over and over again. You can have whatever you want instead of `o` and `c`.

You can even omit those and write this. It's totally upto you what you want.

```sql
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Customers.CustomerName
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.CustomerName='Around the Horn' AND Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID;
```

---

For the second one:

```sql
SELECT CustomerID AS ID, CustomerName AS Customer
FROM Customers;
```

This is aliasing column name. It affects what the columns will be named in the output. Here you can have anything you like instead of `ID` and `Customer`.

> but why do we need `CustomerName AS Customer`? I do not understand, is also not clear, if we choose `CustomerID`, then where do the names come from? we didn't choose them

Here `CustomerID` is the name of one of the columns in the `Customers` table. If you don't alias it the output of that query will show that column's name as `CustomerID`.

It is not required, it's just a preference. It is upto you what you alias them to or even if you want to alias them. (So, you actually did choose them.)

---

Sample output if the query was simply

```sql
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName
FROM Customers;
```

[image]

But in case you alias them, you'll get this output (notice the difference in column names):

[image]

Comment: but i choose CustomerID to be displayed as id, why is CustomerName displayed? if I didn't select it in SELECT CustomerID?

Comment: @EvaSmirnova When you write `SELECT CustomerID AS ID, CustomerName AS Customer`, you are selecting **both** `CustomerID` and `CustomerName`. If you don't want `CustomerName` to be displayed you need to just write `SELECT CustomerID AS ID FROM Customers;`

Comment: It's not clear why I select both if I write only one CustomerID,
it causes a lot of misunderstanding

Comment: @EvaSmirnova It is how `SELECT` works. So, if you've something like `SELECT A FROM X;` then you select only `A`. If you've something like `SELECT A, B FROM X;` then you'll get both `A` and `B`. If you write `SELECT A, B, C FROM X;` you'll get `A`, `B` and `C`. If you write `SELECT * FROM X;` all the columns of that table will be selected.

Comment: This i know,thanks

Answer (score 1):

In SELECT:

- Aliases determine how end user will see the col name so it's OK to hide or customize label of col to more understandable version of col name

In FROM:

- Always is good to use aliases when you have more then one source of data, because you know from which table in SELECT is this col and when 2 table have same col name like ID it's shorter than full table name

Comment: Your explanation is completely incomprehensible to me.

Comment: But it's correct :-) You can alias columns that you select in the `SELECT` clause, so these columns get a different name in your result set. You can alias tables in the `FROM` clause, so you save typing (and get the query more readable) when qualifying the columns in your query, so as to show which table a column belongs to.